# OrientDB embedding mobile

Tags: licensing, data-modeling, orientdb, baasbox

I am working on a pet project mobile app. I am planning to use OrientDB in embedded mode with the app. Here are the questions i have:

1. Am i free to use OrientDB embedded in a mobile application? This application will be distributed for free to users on Android playstore.
2. Can the embedded OrientDB synchronise with Baasbox. At this point in time, the synchronization is only one; from mobile to the api server.

Please let me know. I am a noob with Graph databases in general.

Thanks
S

Comment: Please ask question 1. here instead http://opensource.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

To answer to your questions:

1. Absolutely, OrientDB Community Edition is FREE for any usage (Apache2 License).
2. There is no off-line synchronization in OrientDB, so unless BaasBox implemented it, it's all up to you.